# Visual Studio DLL causes crash when called from Mingw program

Tags: c++, linux, dll

Basically, I have a DLL I wrote in Visual Studio (compiled as C!):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern __declspec(dllexport) int my_dll_test();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And the source file, after including the header, says simply:

```
int my_dll_test()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Then I try to call it from a C++ program compiled with Mingw. As soon as I call that or any other function, the entire program segfaults out with no warning whatsoever. I know this seems like an extremely bizarre thing to do, and its a long story as to why. But I don't understand why such a simple DLL would crash when called.

Comment: Why do you put the `Linux` tag?  Your question has nothing to do with Linux!

Comment: When you compile the client program, the header it includes should have `__declspec(dllimport)`.  Often macro hackery is used to make the header produce one or the other `declspec` depending on whether or not the DLL is being built or not.

Comment: Sorry about the Linux thing, I'm actually cross-compiling from Linux and testing on a Windows Virtual Machine... yes I work in odd conditions.

Okay I'll try import....